# Is there a Tizen Media player app that can sync with IPhone

Tags: media-player, tizen

I am very new to Tizen. I want to know if there is a media player app for Tizen that can sync with IPhone and play audio files stored in the phone.

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not appear to be related to programming.

Comment: I am looking for developing an app for sync with ipod so wanted to know if there is an app already doing that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the official Tizen SDK there is no such application. [Tizen Store](http://www.tizenstore.com/) as of this time is not launched or ready, when they'll do you can search there if there is an applications that does the thing you need.

For now it seems that just the [app seller page](http://seller.tizenstore.com/login/signIn.as) is available in the Tizen store probably because there is a [app contest still in progress](https://developer.tizen.org/contests/tizen-app-challenge).

If you want to do this media player yourself you can do a native approach or a web application aproach, you have [here a sample tutorial and web app using JQuery Mobile](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/multimedia-playback).

.